# Android diagnostic tool for applications

Tags: android, diagnostics

I'm looking for a reliable tool for diagnosing Android apps. I want to get the data of Battery usage and CPU usage. I would prefer to get it in real-time, like those of the built-in Developer Tools, but getting the data after few minutes of using the apps is also fine.
The at&t ARO app is great, but it works only on emulators, and I have to check the apps on a real device, because I'm using the camera, with a lot of image-processing. If I could find a tool like ARO, but for real devices - it would be the best.
(don't offer me apps like Norton Utilities. Those apps are great, but don't fit my needs...)

Thanks,
Yair

Answer (score 0):

Have yout tried PowerTutor? It approximates the battery consumption based on hardware utilization as CPU, WiFi and storage I/O. If you need real power rate values, you will need external power meters, as the standard battery interface is too imprecise.

Answer (score 0):

AT&T ARO is available as Open Source: https://github.com/attdevsupport/ARO  As long as your device is rooted - you are good to go.

Note that ARO does model your camera and network power drain and battery usage, but not CPU.  There is another free Open Source tool from Orange called ATK that will do that for you:
https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/ATK/downloads