# JavaFx project compiles with maven but doesnt execute

Tags: java, maven, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm writting a program in Java and I'm using JavaFX for the GUI. Until today i've using javafx stand alone to code and everything runs smoothly.
I've decided to start using maven and now the project doesnt compile nor does it run or execute.

```
    Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at main.java.Main.start(Main.java:19)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application main.java.Main
```

This is my main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/AuthenticationForm.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Gym Master 1000");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.centerOnScreen();

    root.getChildrenUnmodifiable();
}
```

I have used maven on other projects but never with javafx. What do i do?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755630/javafx-location-is-not-set-error You should not use `..` in the resource name when you are packaging as a jar file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all be sure that your .fxml file is in the same directory as the main class, and use the complete path in the `.getResource("complete path")` and not  `getResource("../fxml/AuthenticationForm.fxml"))` because .. ins´t valid.

Also you can use :

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("completePATH"));
```

Instead:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/AuthenticationForm.fxml"));
```

For more information, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507591/javafx-location-is-required-even-though-it-is-in-the-same-package) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008429/fxml-fxmlloader-error-diagnostic-tools-sought/24010056).
Thanks to James_D from his information.

Comment: [`..` is not a valid resource name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html), so I don't think this will fix it.

Comment: After some research, you are right, "../fxml/AuthenticationForm.fxml" is not a valid name, I will edit my question immediately.Thanks.